# SMS Forwarding with Phone ringer

Tags: twilio

Looking for some advice.  My relative is deaf.  She has a Mi Band on iOS that will vibrate on incoming calls - but no one phones a deaf person!  What she needs is it to vibrate when she gets an SMS - which is not supported on iOS. So I'd like to know how I might setup a cheap SMS number to issue to her friends.  When this number receives an SMS it should forward it intact AND ring her mobile and hang up.  This will vibrate the band.

Can Twilio do this?  Would I need a server to implement it or can it been done via config within the Twilio service?

Thanks for all ideas, Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You could absolutely do this with Twilio. You would need a server with a small application running on it though, I'll explain the flow you would need.

The application would need to be available at a URL that you could setup as the messaging request URL when you purchase the Twilio number. Then, when a message was sent to the number, Twilio will make an HTTP request to the URL.

Your application would have to do two things in response to that request. [To initiate the call, it would need to make a request to the Twilio API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls). In Ruby you could do the following:

```
require "twilio-ruby"

client = Twilio::REST::Client.new("YOUR_TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID", "YOUR_TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN")
client.calls.create(
  :to => "YOUR_RELATIVES_NUMBER",
  :from => "YOUR_TWILIO_NUMBER",
  :url => "http://your-url.com/hangup"
)
```

To forward the message you would need to return some XML, known as [TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml), to [tell Twilio to forward the message](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/message) to your relative's number too. That XML would look like:

```
<Response>
  <Message to="YOUR_RELATIVES_NUMBER" from="YOUR_TWILIO_NUMBER">params["Body"]</Message>
</Response>
```

You'd need one other endpoint for your application, that would [hangup the call when answered](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/hangup). That would return some very simple TwiML like this:

```
<Response>
  <Hangup/>
</Response>
```

All together, using Sinatra as the web framework this would look like:

```
require 'twilio-ruby'
require 'sinatra'

post '/messages' do
  client = Twilio::REST::Client.new("YOUR_TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID", "YOUR_TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN")
  client.calls.create(
    :to => "YOUR_RELATIVES_NUMBER",
    :from => "YOUR_TWILIO_NUMBER",
    :url => "http://your-url.com/hangup"
  )
  twiml = Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
    r.Message params["Body"], :to => "YOUR_RELATIVES_NUMBER", :from => "YOUR_TWILIO_NUMBER"
  end
  return twiml.to_xml
end

post '/hangup' do
  twiml = Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
    r.Hangup
  end
  return twiml.to_xml
end
```

The only downside would be that all the messages would appear to come from the Twilio number, as Twilio doesn't allow number spoofing for SMS messages.

I noticed that you answered a question on StackOverflow with the C# tag. I'm no C# developer, thus the Ruby examples, but the documentation, which I've linked throughout above, has examples in C# too.

Let me know if this helps at all.

Comment: Thanks, very useful, and sorry for the delay in acknowledging.  I am more c# focused but don't worry this will help me evaluate the possibilities.